# swiper with rollupjs is asking for dom7_modular

Tags: swiper.js, rollupjs

When I try to use swiper with rollup I get this:

```
(!) Missing global variable name
Use output.globals to specify browser global variable names 
corresponding to external modules
dom7/dist/dom7.modular (guessing 'dom7_modular')
created public/build/bundle.js in 1.6s
```

and in the console

```
main.js:8 Uncaught ReferenceError: dom7_modular is not defined
at main.js:8
```

any idea about this?

Comment: After updating to the latest rollup I get this:
(!) A plugin is directly adding properties to the bundle object in the "generateBundle" hook. This is deprecated and will be removed in a future Rollup version, please use "this.emitFile" instead.
(!) Unresolved dependencies
https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#warning-treating-module-as-external-dependency
dom7/dist/dom7.modular (node_modules/swiper/js/swiper.esm.bundle.js)

Answer (score 0):

```
    resolve({
        browser: true,
        dedupe: ['svelte'],
        extensions: ['.svelte','.js']
    }),
```

I added just .js to extensions in the rollup config and it was done